# PyQt5 - QLabel padding not work as expected

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

Padding properties is not working as expected.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(450, 450)

        tracking_description = QLabel()
        tracking_description.setStyleSheet('''
                border: 2px solid;
                border-radius: 8px;
                padding-top: 0px;
                padding-bottom: 0px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                padding-left: 10px;
                ''')
        tracking_description.setText("Consente di scegliere una \
                delle camere installate sul territorio e impostarla \
                in <b>modalità tracciante</b>.<br />Durante questa fase \
                il sistema osserverà i veicoli che transitano nella scena \
                e <b>definirà in maniera automatica delle aree di \
                parcheggio</b>.<br />\Propedeuticamente, sarà possibile \
                definire le scene di osservazione che una specifica camerà \
                dovrà gestire.")
        tracking_description.setWordWrap(True)
        tracking_description.setFixedWidth(408)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addWidget(tracking_description)
        vbox.addStretch(1)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addLayout(vbox)
        hbox.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(["TODO"])
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I keep `padding-right` and `padding-left` of **tracking_description** QLabel to **10px**, this is the output (with unexpected top and bottom padding too):

[image: Padding is NOT ok]

If I set `padding-right` and `padding-left` to **30px**, this is the output (with expected top and bottom padding of 0px):

[image: Padding is ok]

Why this behaviour?

Comment: Mh, that seems to be a composite problem, possibly related to the font metrics *and* the requirement of the fixed width. QLabel adjusts its size based on the available space, considering multiple factors including padding, spacing, size constraints, etc, and that's usually a "probability guess" that is sometimes prone to small errors. If you look closely, both boxes have the same height, computed for 10 lines of text. I doubt there is a direct solution for this, the only possible answer would be to use a QTextDocument that will then set a maximum height based on the padding and the contents.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with a QTextDocument!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior. But maybe helps to set "qproperty-indent:0;" in the stylesheet.  Qt adds automatically an indent if this property is negative or not set.

Comment: Oh my god!!!!!
@bzs "qproperty-indent:0;" solve the problem!!!!
Your are a genius!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set *margin* and *padding* on a QLabel you have to set *indent* to zero. Because Qt adds extra space (depending on the alignment) if the value of the indent property is equal to -1 or not set.

```
QLabel 
{
    qproperty-indent:0; /* without px or whatever*/
}
```